# C pointer to array - something I could not explain to myself

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

could someone please explain the following behavior. It leaves me in doubt.

This is my very simple program

```
int main () {
   char str[50];
   int len;

   printf( "str %p, pstr %p\n", str, &str  );

   return(0);
}
```

and this is the program output

```
str 0x7ffd864f1990, pstr 0x7ffd864f1990
```

Why on earth the pointers value are exactly the same?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the decay of arrays into pointers.

In most contexts, when an array name is used it decays to a pointer to the first element of the array.  That's what's happening when you pass `str` to `printf`.  One of the few times this decay *doesn't* happen is when the array is the subject of the address-of operator `&`.  This gives the address of the array itself, which has the same value as the address of the first element.  That's why the printed value is the same.

This conversion is detailed in section 6.3.2.1 of the C standard:

> *3* Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to
>   initialize an array, an expression that has type "array of type" is
>   converted to an expression with type "pointer to type" that points
>   to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If
>   the array object has register storage class, the behavior is
>   undefined.

Although the *types* of the two expressions are different (one is `char *` and the other is `char (*)[50]`), the values of the two pointers are the same.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion. If the types are ordered in respect to the order in the question, it should be (one is `char (*)[50]` and the other is `char *`) Or am I confused now?:)

Comment: @KamiKaze You have it backwards.  :)

Comment: Yes I saw it now as I read the dupe.